# Accessing variable through a passed in object from another class returns null/0

Tags: java, oop, object, variables, null

When I try to access a variable in another class, after passing in the object as a parameter, it just returns null( or in this case 0 for int)

```
import java.util.*;
public class test{

public int rSite;

public void test(){
    rSite = 5;


}
public static void main( String[] args){
   test testing = new test();
   test2.uhh(testing);
}}
```

Then in my second class

```
public class test2{
static test Obj;
public static void uhh(test testingObj){
    Obj = testingObj;
    System.out.println( Obj.rSite );
}}
```

This isn't my original code, I just replicated it in a smaller setting so it would be easier to debug. The output for this is 0, when it should be 5 right?

Comment: You've got a "pseudo" constructor. Constructors don't have return types, not void, not anything.

Comment: Change `public void test(){` to `public test(){`. Also as an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.